# How to check for unoccupied spaces in html5 canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to check for empty spaces in a canvas?

The idea here is to create a map as given below:

[image]

currently I'm using a method to circularly permute child nodes around the parent as follows:

```
function getCircularAngles(points) {
  return [...Array(points).keys()].map(
    (num) => num * ((Math.PI * 2) / points)
  );
}

function getCoorByAngle(
  origin,
  angle,
  radius
) {
  return {
    x: origin.x + Math.sin(angle) * radius,
    y: origin.y + Math.cos(angle) * radius,
  };
}

function getCircularCoords(
  origin,
  points,
  radius
) {
  return getCircularAngles(points).map((angle) =>
    getCoorByAngle(origin, angle, radius)
  );
}
```

But the above approach is not so great. & I want a more efficient way of doing this such that spaces are more preserved and the nodes feels like they are arranged in a grid like manner rather than circular way.

**So the new idea would be to**

1. check for nearest empty spaces at minimum distance.
2. place the child node in such a manner that it won't overlap with others.
3. continue the process for all nodes & child nodes.

Can someone suggest an implementation for this?

**What I've tried**
I tried converting the whole canvas to small cells and then assigned each node to each cell && update the status of the cell as occupied (such that overlap won't occur) and continued it for the remaining nodes. But this approach is not so efficient as it is computationally so much expensive (since I will have to loop through all the cells, find the nearest unoccupied & then assign the node to that cell) && is taking a lot of time to assign position on app initialisation.

**Another idea** would be to check for pixels occupied in the canvas.
like this

```
var ctx = yourCanvas.getContext(); 
var pixelData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
```

in the above `pixelData.data` will be a `Uint8ClampedArray(16000000)`.

But then also to check for empty/ unoccupied spaces will have to loop through and will be computationally expensive

Comment: Can someone please help?

Comment: If you iterate in a spiral pattern outwards the "trying all cells" approach can be made more efficient

Comment: Can you suggest some code? Please...

Comment: Sorry, you are trying to implement a highly complex algorithm which would be a entire project just by itself. I would suggest looking at how third party libraries solve this problem.

Comment: Instead of playing directly with pixels, why not use a 2-D matrix of a fixed size that spans the entire canvas. Each cell in that matrix can be used as a text-box. And checking for empty spaces would be efficient as the size of the matrix will be much much less than the pixel map.

Comment: Yeah. that also I tried. converting to cells/ matrix... that also is computationally expensive as the number of nodes gets higher..

Comment: Dont use pixels for this, instead use rectangles. Place these rectangles in a spatial index and then use the spatial index to query intersections, nearest/k-nearest, or whatever else you need without having scan a billion pixels. You might also look into well studied tree layout algorithms, it looks like you are trying to implement a force directed tree with some aggressive packing.